# ImageDataGenerator is not saving the actual output to the disk

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, data-augmentation, image-preprocessing

I have a training set of images with structure like this:

```
path = /aug-dir/img_dir
             1.jpg
             2.jpg
             ...jpg
```

I am trying to augment the images and save them to disk for future use. I want to implement the below code:

```
## I want to do only mobilenet.preprocess_input and no other data augmentation

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input)
aug_datagen_test = datagen.flow_from_directory(path,
                                               save_to_dir=save_path, ### want to save the images to save_path
                                               save_format='jpg',
                                               target_size=(image_size,image_size),
                                               batch_size=1, 
                                               shuffle = False)
```

When I generate the image, the preprocessing_function (i.e. mobilenet.preprocess_input) is applied properly and I am getting the correct result.

```
for i in range(11):
     imgs, labels = next(aug_datagen_test)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(orginal_image)
plt.title('Original_image')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(imgs[0])
plt.title('output from ImageDataGenerator')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of original image and datagenerator image]

But the ***'output from ImageDataGenerator'*** (the actual output) image is not saved in save_path. This is how the image is saved in save_path after the data augmentation.

[image: image from save_path]

**Am I doing something wrong? Why is the correct output not saved to the disk?**

Please let me know if any further details are required.

***Note:*** I am getting the same output from datagen.flow i.e. the image is not saved properly.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Generally we can save augmented images using `ImageDataGenerator`. Are there any specific reason that are you trying  `mobilenet.preprocess_input` ?